# On efficiency analysis of randomized divide-and-conquer median find

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms

I read following explanation from Dasgupta's Algorithms book for Median finding, this is the same philosophy applied in randomized quick-sort.
Here as per book terminology $S$ denotes array of integers, $v$ is pivot, $S_{L}$ and $S_{R}$ are left and right side of pivot element.

*To distinguish between lucky and unlucky choices of $v$, we will call $v$ good if it lies within the 25th to 75th percentile of the array that it is chosen from. We like these choices of $v$ because they ensure that the sub lists $S_{L}$ and $S_{R}$ have size at most three-fourths that of $S$ (do you see why?), so that the array shrinks substantially. Fortunately, good $v$’s are abundant:
half the elements of any list must fall between the 25th to 75th percentile!*

In one of the interview it was asked to me up till what range this median finding gives average running time of $n$.
i.e. Favourable range of selection is within 25 to 75 percentile. But up to what extent we can reduce this and still have average running time of $n$

My approach was to write recurrence relation and then from the height of the tree comment on average running time, but I doubt is it a correct way to have answer? Also it might not provide tighter bounds.

It will be helpful if someone can also suggest what mathematical tool/technique will be useful for this kind of analysis.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do any calculation. There is absolutely nothing special about the numbers 25 and 75.

If $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$ and you are promised that the median is between the $\alpha$'th percentile and the $\beta$'th percentile, then the running time of the algorithm will be linear. Indeed, if $\gamma = \min(\alpha,1-\beta)$, the length reduces by a factor of at least $1-\gamma$ in each recursive call, so the total running time will be proportional to at most
$$ n \sum_{i=0}^\infty (1-\gamma)^i. $$
Even without computing the sum, we can tell that in converges, so we get a bound of $O(n)$. If we compute the sum, we get the dependence on $\gamma$:
$$ \frac{n}{\gamma}. $$

This sort of behavior always occurs when we reduce a problem to a subproblem which is smaller by a constant factor bounded away from 1. Once you know that, you don't need to do any calculations.